# Problems building Apache Oltu 0.31

Tags: apache, oauth-2.0, oltu

I'd like to run the client demo for Apache Oltu. Following the demo's [instructions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OLTU/OAuth+2.0+Client+Demo) (download and "mvn jetty:run") doesn't work due to missing dependencies, so I'm trying to build the whole project with "mvn install" and running into other missing dependency issues. Here's the tail of the Maven output:

```
[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Apache Oltu - OpenId Connect - Client 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for
org.apache.oltu.oauth2:org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client:jar:0.31-SNAPSHOT is
missing, no dependency information available
[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - Parent .............................. SUCCESS [1.794s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - Parent .................. SUCCESS [0.159s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - Common .................. SUCCESS [2.378s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - Client .................. SUCCESS [2.249s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - HttpClient .............. SUCCESS [1.754s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - Dynamic Registration Common  SUCCESS
[0.381s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - Dynamic Registration Client  SUCCESS
[1.393s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - Authorization Server .... SUCCESS [2.260s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - Resource Server ......... SUCCESS [1.818s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - Resource Server Filter .. SUCCESS [1.434s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - Test Utils .............. SUCCESS [0.350s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - Dynamic Registration Server  SUCCESS
[1.821s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - Integration Tests ....... SUCCESS [3.382s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - JWT ..................... SUCCESS [0.696s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OpenId Connect - Parent ............. SUCCESS [0.080s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OpenId Connect - Common ............. SUCCESS [0.291s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OpenId Connect - Client ............. FAILURE [0.017s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - Demos - Parent ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oltu - Demos - Client ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oltu - Reactor ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 22.735s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Aug 15 16:11:10 PDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/81M
[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project
org.apache.oltu.openidconnect.client: Could not resolve dependencies for
project
org.apache.oltu.openidconnect:org.apache.oltu.openidconnect.client:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT:
Failed to collect dependencies at
org.apache.oltu.oauth2:org.apache.oltu.oauth2.jwt:jar:0.31-SNAPSHOT: Failed
to read artifact descriptor for
org.apache.oltu.oauth2:org.apache.oltu.oauth2.jwt:jar:0.31-SNAPSHOT:
Failure to find
org.apache.oltu.oauth2:org.apache.oltu.oauth2.parent:pom:0.31-SNAPSHOT in
http://repository.apache.org/snapshots was cached in the local repository,
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of
apache.snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Here's what I see in ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/oltu/oauth2/org.apache.oltu.oauth2.parent/0.31-SNAPSHOT

```
-rw-r--r--  1 sherb  staff  248 Aug 15 16:53 org.apache.oltu.oauth2.parent-0.31-SNAPSHOT.pom.lastUpdated
-rw-r--r--  1 sherb  staff  238 Aug 15 16:53 resolver-status.properties
```

Has anyone else seen this and been able to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should be now fixed in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OLTU-112 .